# Add forked repo to parent repo folder, and can pull from both into same folder

Tags: git, github, fork, external

I am having problems pulling a fork from github into a folder, where the parent repo resides.

I already have a working local folder where I can pull parent repo changes into.
Here are my steps:

1. Create local folder for forked repo
2. Fork a repo on github
3. Pull forked repo into local folder
4. Make my changes, commit and push them
5. Github has registered the commits

No problems so far. I have 2 sibling folders, (ORG) one with the original repo and (FORK) one with my fork that I can work on.
Now I need to pull my fork onto a second machine (for testing). Here are the steps on the secondary machine:

1. `cd folderWith ORG repo`
2. `git remote add UniqueName git://github.com/myUserName/forkedRepoName.git`
3. `git branch -a` does not show UniqueName. I think this is where the problem lies
4. `git remote -v` shows both a fetch and push entry for UniqueName. I only need fetch/pull
5. `git branch fork`. Create a new branch so I can switch between ORG and FORK repos
6. `git checkout fork`
7. `git pull UniqueName/master`. "fatal error: 'UniqueName/master' does not appear to be a git repository"

What am I doing wrong ?
I do not wish to have sibling folder on the secondary machine too, only another branch.

**UPDATE:**
`git branch -a` will first show the branches of `UniqueName` *after* you do a `git fetch/pull`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your last command, try `git pull UniqueName master`.

Comment: I just did this, and came back to SO to update my question, but see you answered with the exact same command. This command works.